# Create Service to search websites (with query)?

Tags: automator, services

I would like to create a Mac Service where I could search on some websites, from applications like Scrivener. For example (with "{query}" for where the word should be):

[https://www.google.ca/search?q={query}&safe=strict&biw=1280&bih=636&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnysHu8NDPAhVEax4KHRwxB1AQ_AUICCgB](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%7Bquery%7D&safe=strict&biw=1280&bih=636&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnysHu8NDPAhVEax4KHRwxB1AQ_AUICCgB)

OR

[https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords={query}](https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%7Bquery%7D)

I already have the URLs, like the websites above, but I just need to know how to create the service in Automator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Set the service to receive selected text, then add a Run Shell Script action with the following content, setting the shell to /bin/bash and passing the input as arguments.

```bash
for query in "$@"
do
    open "https://www.google.com/?q=$query"
done
```

Replace the URL with your desired URL, where `$query` is where you would like the selected text to be inserted in the string.

<sup>Also, that's all you need for a Google search — don't bother with the additional session parameters.</sup>