# The Automator website search service I found on AskDifferent breaks in Apple Music/iTunes, how do I fix it?

Tags: itunes, automator, script, apple-music

I made a shortcut to run from the contextual menu.

I want to use it in <strike>iTunes</strike> Apple Music to search discogs for certain albums and singles.

I copied [this workflow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260004/create-service-to-search-websites-with-query).

I modified the code to suit my purpose.

```
for query in "$@"
do
    open "https://www.discogs.com/search/?q=$query&type=all"
done
```

the workflow works within safari, but breaks in Finder and <strike>iTunes</strike> Apple Music.

This is the error it produces within Apple Music and Finder:

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: 
“The file /Users/sveinbjorn/https:/www.discogs.com/
?q=search/?q=Renegade Master&type=all does not exist.”
```

So I guess I'm trying to figure out how to make the automator workflow and the shell script work in the Music app and in finder.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: I have no problem in **macOS Catalina** with **Finder** or **Music** using the **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_ with a **Run Shell Script** _action_ using the _code_ in your question.